# Find regex and append it

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to compare 2 CSV files to find the differences. Those 2 files look like this:

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
['Steve'], ['Stevens'], ['s.stevens@company.com']
['Sarah'], ['Stevens'], ['sarah.stevens@company.com']
```

and

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
...
['Richard'], ['McBait'], ['ilovecats123@mail.mcbait.com']
```

What I'm trying to do is to compare those 2 files without having to create temporary files. The script should be able to exclude characters `[`,`'` and `]`, read the values and then compare 2 files with each other, representing the "new users".

I solve this problem using this (likely wrong) logic:

```
read the file -> execute subprocess (tr -d \[\]\') -> save output to file1_temp -> read the file1_temp -> convert to set -> compare (.difference) with file2_tmp
```

So, the question is, is there any faster way to solve this problem? For example like in Perl, by using `if line` regex to determine what data will be read.

Comment: Will both files fit into memory? Does the comparison go line-by-line, such as to say line 1 of file A compares with line 1 of file B, or is it any line in the file?

Comment: I don't know actually, but we suggest that those csv files contain 300-400 lines. In my case, I know that new users will be added in the end of the file, however, line-by-line comparison is also OK, I'm just learning.

Comment: To solve same (not real world scenario) problem in Perl, I used if line regex before putting data in to the hash.

Comment: what is the expected result of the example you posted? Is John Johnson also a diff since the email address differs? Or is only Richard McBait the diff as this line is not present in the first file?

Comment: Also you should take a look at python's `re` module for regex, and a `for line in file` loop. It sounds like you can fit the files into memory and make a `set` of `tuple`s. Once you check those out and try a solution, come back here and post your code if you get stuck.

Comment: Oh, snap! Typo with John Johnson. Your second statements is fully correct, its only Richard McBait who should be printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
```

and

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
```

is not the same user in your case, load each csv file in a list  (in memory) and get the delta of these two lists (using set).

file1.csv :

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
['Steve'], ['Stevens'], ['s.stevens@company.com']
['Sarah'], ['Stevens'], ['sarah.stevens@company.com']
```

file2.csv :

```
['John'], ['Johnson'], ['1337@john-johnson.pro']
['Steve'], ['Stevens'], ['s.stevens@company.com']
['Richard'], ['McBait'], ['ilovecats123@mail.mcbait.com']
```

Here is the code:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('file1.csv') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     list1 = map(tuple, reader)
...
>>> with open('file2.csv') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     list2 = map(tuple, reader)
...
>>> delta = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
>>> print delta
[("['Sarah']", " ['Stevens']", " ['sarah.stevens@company.com']")]
>>> clean_delta = [tuple(x.strip().strip('[\'\']') for x in y) for y in delta]
>>> print clean_delta
[('Sarah', 'Stevens', 'sarah.stevens@company.com')]
```

Comment: However, special characters are still read by Python, I mean `[`, `]` and `'`

Comment: clean_delta = [tuple(x.strip().strip('[\'\']') for x in y) for y in delta]

Comment: Thank you Thomas! Now I have to read and understand your solution, thanks mate :)